# Displaying image from the sqlite database using cursor in android

Tags: android, image, sqlite

i want to display image in imageview from sqlite database using cursor. i used below code to retrieve image but i am not able to display image in imageview.

```
Cursor c=this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "name","price","image" },
                null, null, null, null, null);
name.setText(c.getString(0));
price.setText(c.getString(1));
byte b[]=c.getBlob(2);
Bitmap bp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
//ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);               
//Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
//image.setImageBitmap(theImage);               
image.setImageBitmap(bp);
```

other than image, name and price will display but image will not display.
any suggestion or code that will help me to solve this problem.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What's the field type in the SQLite db for your 'image' column?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've tried to use Stream instead of byte array, mine example simply works for me. 
Also try to use Cursor.getColumnIndex()

```
    byte[] blob = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(YourDB.IMAGE));
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

Here's my "create table" statement, pls double check yours

```
    create table datatable(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, image BLOB, price INTEGER);
```

Comment: First guess is simple, column count starts with 1 and therefore column idx=2 is price, definitely not blob.

Comment: Why decodeStream() instead of decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);

Comment: That was not proven as root cause of the problem. I've just advised that my codepiece is working, not stating opposite statement about byteArray decoding.

Answer (score 2):

First of all please did not store the images in database because sqlite will not support more then 1 mb,i may be wrong, images should be store in assets or drawble folder and the name of images should be store in database then you can get it from name to resource conversion by code

```
 String videoFileName= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TB_SETTING_VIDEOFILENAME));
        int dot = videoFileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        videoFileName=videoFileName.substring(0,dot);
        Log.d("VIDEOFILENAME", videoFileName);

        int videoFileRId = getResources().getIdentifier(videoFileName , "raw", getPackageName());
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

try this
cursor object; // your cursor

```
   mImageView.setImageBitmap(getImageFromBLOB(object.getBlob(object.getColumnIndex("book_thumb"))));

    public static Bitmap getImageFromBLOB(byte[] mBlob)
    {
        byte[] bb = mBlob;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length);
    }
```

Comment: :Hello , if you want to help me with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954896/how-to-save-image-taken-from-camera-and-show-it-to-listview-crashes-with-ille . Thanks