# Display image in gridview based on image path inside database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, gridview, android-gridview

I have saved a few images inside the phone and inserted the image path into the database.
I wanted to use the image path inside the database and display it out in gridview.
For now I could create a gridview to display out images in gallery app. But I don't really know how to display image out based on the database path. If possible could anyone enlighten me in this issue? Any comment will be appreciated.

The code below I used to display images in gallery.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.phone_tab);

    final String[] columns = { MediaColumns.DATA, BaseColumns._ID };
    final String orderBy = BaseColumns._ID;
    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
            null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DATA);
        thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        arrPath[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }
    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imagecursor.close();

    final Button selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select_btn);
    selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            for (int i =0; i<len; i++)
            {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i]){
                    cnt++;
                    selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                }
            }
            if (cnt == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please select at least one image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You've selected Total " + cnt + " image(s).",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);

                Intent input = new Intent(v.getContext(), InputScreen.class);
                input.putExtra("selectImages", selectImages+"");
                StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
                replaceContentView("InputScreen", input);

            }


        }



    });



}
```

Values [2] return as /mnt/sdcard/ImageFolder/Image1.jpg.

```
    String values[] = helper.get_user_image(useremail);
    String filepath = values[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you store image path instead of image in database.Access those images using image path that is stored in database.

If you must have to use image at database

- Please use Stream instead of byte array

The following resources may help you

- [Displaying image from the sqlite database using cursor in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342798/displaying-image-from-the-sqlite-database-using-cursor-in-android)
- [How to display images from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168427/how-to-display-images-from-database)
- https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html